# how to limit an image to it's real shape

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

How can I use an image that whenever I want to make a collision in XNA, it happens only for area of the shape not around of it.

For example when I use below picture, I want collision detection happens only when arrow in shape is touched.

[image: example image]

The collision detection happens in the area in this picture

[image: hit box]

How can I make limitation for area of image only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is also to create two rectangles. That makes the overlapping area (the area there the image isn't but the rectangle) a bit smaller. But if you need to do this pixel excact you have to use the recource-expensive per-pixel-collision.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try restricting the image shape, because regardless of your efforts - you will have a rectangle. What you need to do is work with detecting pixel collisions. It is a fairly extensive topic - you can read more about a Windows Phone-specific XNA implementation [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/XNA-for-Silverlight-developers-Part-7-Collision-detection.aspx).